# Divisor function inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that:
$$\sigma(n) \leq n(\omega(n) + 1),$$
where: $\sigma(n)$ - sum of divisors function and $\omega(n)$ - number of prime divisors function.

Comment: Do you know how $\sigma(n)$ depends on the prime factorisation of $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For

$$n = \prod_{j = 1}^{\omega(n)} p_j^{a_j}$$

with $p_j < p_{j+1}$, we have

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \prod_{j=1}^{\omega(n)} \frac{p_j^{a_j+1}-1}{p^{a_j}(p_j-1)} < \prod_{j=1}^{\omega(n)} \frac{p_j}{p_j-1}.$$

Now, since we indexed the primes dividing $n$ in ascending order, we certainly have $p_j \geqslant j+1$, and hence $\frac{p_j}{p_j-1} \leqslant \frac{j+1}{j}$, so

$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \prod_{j=1}^{\omega(n)} \frac{j+1}{j} = \omega(n)+1.$$

Comment: Great, my solution is the same! Using similar method You can also show that: 
$$\sigma(n) < n \cdot 2^{\omega(n)}.$$